# Differences between FDT profiler and Flash Builder profiler?

Tags: flash, profiler

I'm currently hunting a memory leak related to XML objects. FDT's profiler shows results that match my expectations while Adobe's profiler doesn't show any XML objects at all.

Are there any differences between Adobe's profiler that comes with Flash Builder and FDT's profiler or is that a configuration issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know FDT's profiler but I know that Adobe's profiler hides standard AS3 classes by default.

To the right of the "Live Objects" panel there is a "filter" button. That opens a window which holds among other things, the "Exclude global built-in items (e.g. String)" checkbox. Uncheck it and you'll see XML objects listed too.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thanks. :) I'd never have thought about the filter.